# Best way for two way encrypted authentication in Java RMI api

Tags: java, authentication, encryption, rmi, public-key-encryption

One way is to send `id` in plain text, but this is not secure. man on middle or other client can manipulate plain text information. I want to implement two way authentication between `server` and `client`.